# Control Panel/MCP: Table class in older versions of EE2

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, module, table, table-class

Have there been any changes to the table class in EE2? I have a bug report on an add-on from a user with EE v2.3.1. They've received the following error in my mcp. file:

```
<b>Fatal error:</b> Call to undefined method CI_Table::set_columns()
```

My code looks like this, nothing looks amiss:

```
$this->EE->load->library('table');
$this->EE->table->set_columns(array(
    // column mappings
));
```

And things work fine in 2.5.5. Here's the EE documentation I relied on:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/table.html

Thanks for any insight you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked, and the `EE_Table` class, as well as the `EE_Table::set_columns()` method were introduced in EE 2.4.0.

Before that, EE only included the default CodeIgniter (v2.0.1) table class.

Comment: That'd be the reason. Thanks! Can you point me to where you found that? I did a quick Find in the Change Log for "set_columns", which wouldn't have found the whole table class.

Comment: No reference sorry.. I have an archive of old EE versions and just opened them up to check for you. 2.3.1 doesn't have the `EE_Table` class at all.

Comment: Granted, I just read the changelog for 2.4.0 and can't find any mention of it. So you'll just have to take my word for it.